# Позиционирование фона в raphaeljs

Tags: raphael, svg, javascript

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если фон для объекта path устанавливается так:

```
    pathElement.attr({
        'fill':'url("venice.jpg")',
        'stroke-width' : 0
    });
```

То как сдвинуть вон в объекте средствами raphaeljs?

Answer (score 1):

```
pathElement.attr({
    'fill':'url("venice.jpg")',
    'stroke-width' : 0,
    'x': -1000,
    'y': -400
});
```

Так проверьте, [вдруг я прав](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr).

Comment: Нет, к сожалению так не работает.

Comment: @easy а вот так? http://jsfiddle.net/daFpq/

Comment: @lampa Да, как вариант можно, если один элемент. Но у меня их много. Я работаю над игрой в пазлы. Там их много получается и они все друк к другу в плотную стоять должны ну и соответственно складываться в картинку. Рафаэль содает дополнительный элемент, в который помещает фон и его позиционирует при  помощим матрицы этого элемента. Если работает SVG то создается "pattern", если vml то rvml:skew. Можно ли к ним обратиться через рафаэль и изменить их матрицу?

Comment: @easy мм, вот это уже не подскажу, пока так не углублялся.